# Calculate the total number of typed words in a pdf with multiple form fields. (javascript)

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, word-count, form-fields

My very first javascript question here, so this might be very basic.
I'm currently preparing a pdf form with multiple form entry fields that allow user input in Adobe Acrobat PRO DC.

The user is asked to answer a number of essay style questions and fill in their text responses into each field. Depending on the question the length of the answer could range between a few words to hundreds of words.

I now simply want to add an additional field that uses javascript in the calculation tab (custom calculation script) that counts the number of typed words in all the previous fields and displays (to the user) the total number of words that a user has written.

My very first primitive approach was to first create an additional (invisible) field, that simply concatenate all answers of the different fields into one big answer and afterwards count the number of words of that field.

Here some example code:

```
 //first step combine all answers

this.getField("allAnswers").value = this.getField("question1").value + " " +
                                    this.getField("question2").value + " " +
                                    this.getField("question3").value + " " +
                                    this.getField("question4").value;         
//code would proceed until the last question


//A function to count the words which is defined as a general Document script
//("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-count-a-number-of-words-in-given-string-in-javascript")
  
function countWords(str) {
     str = str.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
     str = str.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
     str = str.replace(/\n /,"\n");
     return str.split(' ').length;
  }

//using that function on the allAnswers field
this.getField("totalNumberOfWords").value= countWords(this.getField("allAnswers").value);
```

Although this approach copied the different answers into the "allAnswers" field and subsequently counted the words, I see that strings from different fields are included multiple times, thus inflating the word count very quickly. Why is that the case?
I'm also a bit concerned that this procedure might be causing the pdf itself to run more slowly, especially if many form fields (more than 50) are evaluated at the same time and every time the user types something. Maybe instead inserting a button to manually allow the user to run the script would be better?

What would be a more stable and elegant approach to this?
Thanks already for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not iterate over questions and count words separately? Not sure why you concatenate it.

```
function countAllWords() {
    var wordsCount = 0;
    var lastQuestionIndex = 4;
    for(var i = 1; i <  lastQuestionIndex; i++) {
        var answerText = this.getField("question" + str(i)).value;
        wordsCount += countWords(answerText);
    }
    return wordsCount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!In the document the names of the fields are more descriptive,but therefore vary. I've tried to rewrite the code:

var fieldNames = new Array("field1", "name2", "answer", "test");

function countAllWords() {
    var wordsCount = 0;
    var lastQuestionIndex = 4;
    for(var i = 0; i <  lastQuestionIndex; i++) {
        var answerText = this.getField(fieldNames[i]).value;
        wordsCount += countWords(answerText);
    }
    return wordsCount;
}

Would this work?
Where exactly is the "wordsCount" displayed? I would like to post it into the "totalNumberOfWords" field.

Comment: I imagine you could do `this.getField("totalNumberOfWords").value = countAllWords();`